# Looking for OpenFlow capable Converged Switch

Tags: networking, switch, fibre-channel, openflow

I'm looking for a switch with the following features:

- has GBit and 10GBit ethernet interfaces
- has FibreChannel Uplink ports (4 & 8 Gbit)
- can use OpenFlow to regulate network traffic.

Does anyone know such a device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is one, and there may never be one for that matter. The reason is that network hardware manufacturers not only see OpenFlow as something of threat but also an incomplete spec as if focusses too much on what consider to be the low-end of the market. Both Cisco and Brocade for instance have announced that they will be developing either competing functionally-equivalent superset protocols in the future or hybrid scenarios to provide them with what they believe corporates and service-providers need over the basic spec.

That said there are lots of 1/10Gbps Ethernet switches that can also take FC ports such as Cisco's Nexus 5000-series boxes - just no OpenFlow, but they do have similar, but proprietary functionality.